# Issue with multiplayer interpolation

Tags: unity, multiplayer, interpolation

In a fast-paced multiplayer game I'm working on, there is an issue with the interpolation algorithm. This interpolation is for a moving object not controlled by the local computer.

The server sends packets with the object's position at a fixed rate. (red markers) The interpolation algorithm is attempting (and failing) to create a smooth path between the red markers.

The results of this interpolation are shown by green and black markers. Green is the local position at the exact time a packet is received, and black is the local position at every frame.

**Green:** Local position when a packet is received (edited for clarity)

**Red:** Position received from packet (goal)

**Blue:** Line from local position to goal when packet is received

**Black:** Local position every frame

On a network with a realistic amount of lag and packet loss, this is the result:

[image: Bad stuff]

The local position (green&black lines) seems to oscillate around the goals (red lines) instead of moving between them smoothly.

This is how it looks on a perfect network with the object moving right to left. (0 ping, 0 packet loss, etc.)

[image: Good stuff]

The code works like this:

1. Every x ms, receive a packet with a Vector3 position
2. Set the `goal` to that position
3. Set the `positionAtLastPacket` to the current local position
4. Every frame, lerp from `positionAtLastPacket` to `goal`, attempting to reach the goal approximately when the next packet should arrive.
5. If the next packet takes longer than expected, interpolation continues past the goal and becomes extrapolation.

I believe what is happening is the extrapolation overshoots a bit to far. Over several packets, this issue compounds, causing the oscillation.

```
    // local transform position when the last packet arrived. Will lerp from here to the goal
    private Vector3 positionAtLastPacket;

    // location received from last packet
    private Vector3 goal;

    // time since the last packet arrived
    private float currentTime;

    // estimated time to reach goal (also the expected time of the next packet)
    private float timeToReachGoal;

    private void PacketReceived(Vector3 position, float timeBetweenPackets)
    {
        positionAtLastPacket = transform.position;

        goal = position;

        timeToReachGoal = timeBetweenPackets;
        currentTime = 0;

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.up, Color.cyan, 5); // current local position
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, goal, Color.blue, 5); // path to goal
        Debug.DrawRay(goal, Vector3.up, Color.red, 5); // received goal position
    }

    private void FrameUpdate()
    {
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;

        float delta = currentTime/timeToReachGoal;
        transform.position = FreeLerp(positionAtLastPacket, goal, currentTime / timeToReachGoal);

        // current local position
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.up * 0.5f, Color.black, 5);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Lerp without being locked to 0-1
    /// </summary>
    Vector3 FreeLerp(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, float t)
    {
        return from + (to - from) * t;
    }
```

Any idea about what's going on?

Comment: "You can see it clearly in the image below" - No I can't. I have not even found Cyan yet.. "As you can see, the local position seems to oscillate around the goals" - Can not see that either .. Cyan sticks oscillates? Around red sticks? Not sure that is evident.

Comment: @KromStern Fixed the image. Cyan was probably a bad choice for something that needed to stand out against the sky.

By "oscillate" I mean the local position whips back and forth perpendicular to the target path (red) instead of following it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, at least green lines are visible now ;) Still can't make any sense out of it - I just see 3 set of sticks and no idea why they are right or wrong.

Comment: @KromStern I'll describe it in a different way. Red lines are positions received from the server, green&black lines are positions of interpolation. This is very bad, since interpolation should be _between_ the red lines, not all over the place. (I've also edited the post again with details on how the code works)

Comment: Am I getting your expected result right: green lines should be aligned with objects movement, blue lines should be going along series of red lines and black lines should be in between red lines?

Comment: @KromStern That's correct. Their orientation doesn't matter though, each one (except for blue) is just a marker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14863/discussion-between-krom-stern-and-ben-cracknell).

Comment: This still isn't very clear. Perhaps you can provide more than one sentence about what the problem is?

Comment: As mentioned in chat, Ben deals with very high lag (5sec). Each red line is a position separated 1/20th of a sec form the next red line. So what we see on the screen is very vague since Red lines connected with a Green line are almost 100 ticks old, and the actual objects position (100th red line) is not even on the screen. All-n-all I think this post is very poorly formulated.

Comment: @KromStern That's right. I've attempted again to improve the post with more information. Like I said in chat, there were way too many assumptions I was making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, it turns out my router was messed up, causing the game to fall back on TCP without warning. Everything is working fine now, I'm just stupid.

I should have realized something was wrong when the packets started coming in like this:

[image]

There were many other things causing the game to fall back on TCP. Some of them are specific to TNet (my framework) but I'll list them off just in case:

- The Unity Web player doesn't support UDP at all for security reasons.
- Using a VPN to connect back to a server on your local network (in an attempt to test with high ping) will often cause UDP to fail. I don't know why exactly, so it might be specific to my VPN.
- Mixing up the ports for a TNet server, or connecting on the wrong ports. It's a bit confusing to get right, so here is the *correct* way: (using example port numbers)

Create:

```
TNServerInstance.Start(TCP_PORT, UDP_PORT, null, BROADCAST_PORT);
```

Discovery on LAN:

(set your lobby port to BROADCAST_PORT)

Connect:

```
TNManager.Connect(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, TCP_PORT);
```

---

Overall, I highly recommend getting a VPS to host your server for testing, which would have made fixing this problem much easier to discover and find. Digital Ocean has served me well, and it only costs $5/month for more badnwidth and power than I would ever need.